# Recover git losses after branch?

Tags: git

I seem to have lost some code after a mistaken branch, and hope that someone can help me recover it. I was following SO advice as I was working....

I had made a bunch of changes, to a single file related to email processing, in my master branch, and eventually realized that I should have done this work in a separate branch, because it was taking too long and the changes were too significant, and I needed to work on a hotfix. I did not commit the e-mail code, since it wasn't ready to be committed. Following a guide here, I did the following:

```
$ git checkout -b email # to create the new branch with my current work
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --soft HEAD~3 # intended to get master back to original state
$ git pull # make sure I'm up-to-date
# seemed not to work, so I tried:
$ git checkout -- lib/email.rb # intended to get this file back to orig state in the master branch
```

I then created a hotfix branch, worked on that, merged it to master, and deleted it.

I then returned to my "email" branch, but the changes I made are not there; it reverted to something from some time ago. And I don't know why, since I didn't (intentionally) do anything in the "email" branch. Obviously the work is not in the master branch either, because I reset this.

My reflog looks like this, for the relevant time (which was just an hour ago, so hopefully not garbage-collected yet):

```
87067bb HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to email
41fddb9 HEAD@{5}: merge hotfix: Fast-forward
87067bb HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from hotfix to master
41fddb9 HEAD@{7}: commit: refactored database call to avoid need to send DB info
87067bb HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from email to hotfix
87067bb HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from hotfix to email
87067bb HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to hotfix
87067bb HEAD@{11}: pull: Fast-forward
154f1f3 HEAD@{12}: reset: moving to HEAD~3
87067bb HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from email to master
87067bb HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from master to email
```

Is there any way I can get this code back? (No one else has been working on the project during this time.) Thank you!

Comment: Learning hard the first rule of git: "when you don't know where you are, what you should do next, commit! Your work will be saved and you will always be able to recover one way or the other..." Even if your work is not ready to be **pushed**, you will be able to amend the commit, cherrypick or modify the local history, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> `git checkout -b email`
>
> I then returned to my "email" branch, but the changes I made are not there; it reverted to something from some time ago.

No, it did not. You never did anything with that branch; you only created the branch itself, which is just a label pointing to whatever commit you were on at the time (`master`, I guess).

You would have needed to `git add`  and `git commit` your changes.

> And I don't know why,

*This* is your problem. While it is fine to use SE for cracking hard nuts regarding `git` and similar things, it is more important to get some basic understanding about it from other sources, beforehand. If not, it is very easy for you to fall into the "tutorial" trap - i.e., just execute some commands where you don't really have an idea about what they do, without having the bigger picture.

So... the online "git book" on http://git-scm.com is your friend. Read it, at least the few chapters relevant to your day-to-day operations, and you should be fine for most uses of `git`.

When typing commands from SE, I also strongly urge you to find out what they do. For `git` this means `git help`. Like `git help checkout` in this particular example. The included reference pages are extremely well written and usually explain *exactly* what's going on, at least after you got the basics down (what is a commit, what is a branch and so on).

I hope this does not come over as condescending. If there was a way to recover your files, I would have explained that, but unfortunately you wiped them out without any trace (unless you maybe have a filesystem backup, maybe you are on a snapshotting filesystem... unlikely I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the email code wasn't committed.

> I did not commit the e-mail code, since it wasn't ready to be committed.

If that is the case, Git has no record of it and it is impossible to recover, as Git only stores commits.  The notion of code "not being ready to commit" does not apply to Git, since no one else can see the commits you make, unless you choose to push them. Some options for saving work in progress:

- Make a work in progress branch, and save your changes there.

  ```
  git checkout -b email-wip  
  git add .  
  git commit -m "Still working on this"
  ```
- Commit often to the Email branch, but use [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to condense these to "shareable" commits before pushing.

  ```
  git add .  
  git commit -m "Squash this later, still in progress"  
  git checkout master  
  [some time later]  
  git checkout email-branch  
  [fix things up]  
  git add .  
  git commit -m "Good professional commit message here"  
  git rebase -i   
  [Follow text prompt to combine above commits. No one will ever see the temporary one.]  
  git push
  ```
- Use the [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) command.

  ```
  git stash  
  git checkout master  
  [do hot fix stuff]  
  git checkout email-branch  
  git stash pop
  ```